# Count returns duplicate of another count in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I can not find where is the problem, my COUNT() returns the same number for both values *contracts_count* and *records_count*. When using only one of counts, everything works fine. Principle of this query: access company table, get it's id and name, *company* and *group* is related with foreign key in *contract* table, and *record* has foreign key related to *group* table. So I join company with contracts to get contracts count of each company and join group with contracts, records with group to get records count of each company.

```
SELECT 
`company`.`id`,
`company`.`name`,
COUNT(`contract`.`contract_id`) AS contracts_count, 
COUNT(`record`.`record_id`) AS records_count
                    FROM `company`
                    LEFT JOIN `contract`
                            ON `company`.`id`=`contract`.`fk_companystudijos_id`
                    LEFT JOIN `group` 
                            ON `contract`.`fk_groupID`=`group`.`id`
                    LEFT JOIN `record` 
                            ON `group`.`id`=`record`.`fk_groupID`
                            GROUP BY `company`.`id`
                            ORDER BY contracts_count DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT()` counts the number of rows with non-`NULL` values of its argument.  That is pretty much the same for your two columns.

I'm pretty sure you want `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT `contract`.`contract_id`) AS contracts_count, 
COUNT(DISTINCT `record`.`record_id`) AS records_count
```

Comment: I have tried to use DISTINCT before, but I put it only on one COUNT(), thank you for the quick answer.